# How to download enterprise signed apps from Hockeyapp (or similar) in iPad OS?

Tags: ios, enterprise, hockeyapp

After updating to iPadOS 13 I can no longer download apps from HockeyApp since the Safari browser now just downloads the file instead of installing the app.

Answer (score 4):

To re-enable the old behavior and send an iOS user agent to a website, you can enable this workaround *per site*:

1. Tap on the "ᴀA" symbol in Safari's URL bar

   [image: Website options popup in Safari on iPadOS]
2. Tap on "Website Settings" and deselect "Request Desktop Website"

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: Go to Settings->Safari->Request Desktop Website and disable All Websites. Then reload the page in hockeyapp and the button will display install instead of download